# Data warehousing (ETL): Scheduled data migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, etl, automation

I've been assigned task of data warehousing for Reporting and data analysis. Let me first explain what we are going to do.

**Step 1**. Replicate production server `MySQL` database.

**Step 2**. `Scheduled ETL`: Read replicated database (`MySQL`) and push data to `PostgreSQL`.

Now I need your help on **Step 2.**

**Note:** I want `saveOrUpdate` functionality. If `id` is available then update it or save it. Data will be picked up based on `modified` date.

**So is there any tool available for `scheduled` data push in `PostgreSQL`?, Considering my requirements.**

If there ain't any tool available then which programming language I should use for ETL? And other pointers you can provide me to achieve this.

Comment: What is your (or your team's) skillset?

Comment: Why mix MySQL and Postgres?